# Automatically adding custom header to message based on request scope

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

RequestClients in my ApiGateway are injected (using default MS DI) in HTTP request handlers (in those handlers I have access to current request scope). What I want is to automatically, for each RequestClient, to add custom message header where I could put some data from request scope. Use case is to take JWT from request and add it to message as custom header. Then on consumer side I need, for each received request, check that custom header, verify JWT, and add some data from it to consumed request scope so I could access for example IUserContext or something like that. I want to avoid manually adding jwt to message contract for example.

How I can configure MassTransit on Client and Consumer side to achieve what I want? I already read docs about middleware and pipes and observers but still I can't figure it out...

Using RabbitMQ transport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is pretty complicated to put into a post, so I [created a complete sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-ScopedFilters) that shows how to use MassTransit Scoped Filters.

In this sample, an action filter is registered with the controllers to automatically extract the `Token` header and store it so that it can be used when publishing or sending messages from a controller. The MassTransit filters are configured on the bus, so they're available to all receive endpoints.